# 240V to 110V using a Step-Down Transformer

Tags: soldering-iron-station

I was wondering if there is anything I need to be concerned about in regards to using a step-down transformer to power my Weller WES51 soldering iron which is rated at 110V in the UK (mains is 240V in UK).

Comment: just make sure to have the power rating of the device less than the transformer. i think weller doesnt have fuse on their primary input so maybe you can take care of that. if you want.

Comment: *...weller doesnt have fuse on their primary input* indeed, as discovered by Dave of the EEVBlog connecting his 120 V Weller to 240 V: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8itTKH5tj3s   Your WES51 also doesn't appear to have a primary fuse so make sure you never connect it to 240 V.

Comment: Is the weller good with a 50Hz supply?  if not you might need to go with 100V instead of 120 and take a 40% performance hit,

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the output current rating of the step-down transformer is higher than what your station consumes.